# Why wont this pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to run this as a Process from multiprocessing, but when starting the thread the pickler falls over and I can't work out what is stopping it from pickling. I've tried commenting out the socket code and the message obj code, but still not working - what am I doing wrong?

```
class TransmitThread(Process):

    def __init__(self, send_queue, reply_queue, control_pipe, recv_timeout=2, buffer_size=4096):
        """
            This init function is called when the thread is created. Function simply calls the Process class init
            function, and stores the class vars.
        """
        # Call process class init
        Process.__init__(self)

        # Store class vars
        self.send_queue     = send_queue
        self.reply_queue    = reply_queue
        self.control_pipe   = control_pipe
        self._recv_timeout  = recv_timeout
        self._buffer_size   = buffer_size

    def run(self):
        """
            This is the main function that is called when the thread is started.
            The function loops forever, waiting for a send message in the queue, and processes the message to send
            and fetches the response. The thread loops forever until it's terminated or the KILL THREAD command is
            passed through the control pipe.
        """
        # Start our forever running loop
        while True:

            # Check if there is anything in the pipe
            if self.control_pipe.poll():
                # Check if we received the kill thread command
                if self.control_pipe.recv() == KILL_THREAD_COMMAND:
                    # Kill the while loop and end the thread
                    break

            # Check if there is anything in message queue
            if not self.send_queue.empty():
                # Fetch message from the queue to send, and unpickle
                message_obj, message_pickle = self.send_queue.get()

                # Open socket and set timeout
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                sock.settimeout(self._recv_timeout)

                # Connect socket to the recipient
                sock.connect( message_obj.recipient_address )

                # Push the pickled message down the socket
                sock.sendall(message_pickle)

                # Check if the message we send is a request (should get a response)
                if str(message_obj.message_type) == str(Message.REQUEST):

                    print "fetching reply"

                    # Lets fetch the response, and push the pickled message onto the queue
                    self.reply_queue.put( sock.recv(self._buffer_size) )

                    print "got a reply"

                # All done, close the socket
                sock.close()

            # Add small delay to stop this thread consuming too much CPU time
            sleep(0.1)
```

---

The error message is:

```
File "C:/Users/oliver/OneDrive/GIT/pyke/pyke.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.thread.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: How do the messages look like? What is the error message from the pickler? Where does the failure occur? Are you sure, you already have the full message (`recv()` may return short)?

Comment: I've added the error messages from the pickler. I've tried commenting out the recv() call, and all the socket functions and it still doesn't work. I had this working about an hour ago, and I can't work out what I changed to bork it.

Comment: My `thread` module doesn't have `thread.lock`, either. So maybe you've set up some paths differently to modify what python knows as `thread` module? Btw, you should mention your version of python.

Comment: `Thread.__init__(self)` also seems wrong to me, because you inherit from `Process` (probably `multiprocessing.Process`). Are you mixing `multiprocessing` and `threading` modules?

Comment: @dhke Sorry thats a typo. I've switched back to the Thread class for testing because that works. In the code proper its Process.__init__(self)

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺI'm running Py 2.7. I've not changed path as far as I'm aware. In fact this is a newly installed windows box, I've only installed python and a couple of packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pickler error comes from `multiprocessing.Process` trying to internally pickle itself to the subprocess. I'm pretty sure one of your instance variables doesn't pickle properly to the child process. Which one is not clear from your question

```
    # Store class vars
    self.send_queue     = send_queue
    self.reply_queue    = reply_queue
    self.control_pipe   = control_pipe
    self._recv_timeout  = recv_timeout
    self._buffer_size   = buffer_size
```

[Edit after comments from OP]:

The problem was that `send_queue` and `reply_queue` were `Queue.Queue`s rather than `multiprocessing.Queue`. When forking the child worker, `Process` tries to serialize itself and any instance variables over to the child. However `Queue.Queue`s are local objects that are not serializable, hence the error.

Also related to the question is the fact that, `multiprocessing.Queue` [re-uses the exceptions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#L20) from `Queue` without re-exporting these. This [is actually documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues), albeit somewhat hidden beneath the clutter:

> **Note:** `multiprocessing` uses the usual `Queue.Empty` and `Queue.Full`exceptions to signal a timeout. They are not available in the `multiprocessing` namespace so you need to import them from `Queue`.

Comment: You're right, but this is a typo in posting to SO more than anything. I'm switching between Thread and Process during my testing, because Thread works all the time and Process doesn't. I'm importing Process from multiprocessing, and Thread from threading as you would expect. Fixing this doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: hurr. I'm a bit confused now. The reply and send queues are Queue() objects. I'm using them to push data back and forth between the process and the parent that spawned it. What have I done wrong? So the parent has the queue obj and the process has it, and you push data between the two. That is my data link between processes - is that not exactly how queue is supposed to be used?

Comment: @Oliver I have no idea, but one of  those objects doesn't make it to the child process. The pickler tells you the object in question is holding a thread lock object that cannot get serialized. Any candidates come to mind? And yes, `multiprocessing.Queue`s are supposed to work fine this way (they get pickled as proxies which make calls through to the manager).

Comment: pox and buggeration. Right I made an ASSumption that the Queue and multiprocessing.Queue classes were the same and swapped them round. You're right in that the pickler is barfing over the queue - its not the kind of queue that can be pickled. I only swapped them because I couldn't work out how to import the multiprocessing.Queue Empty exception.

Comment: The exception it raises is from the normal Queue module - which is weird in my eyes but never mind.

Comment: Yeah, [`multiprocessing.queues`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#L20) actually imports `Queue.Empty`, but does not re-export it.